# Why are questions being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

[This](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33711/will-evoke-trigger-on-a-creature-thats-returned-to-the-battlefield-from-the-gra) question is -2
[This](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33719/what-sets-are-legal-in-momir-basic) question is 2

I don't see the latter being any more 'valid' of a question.

Comment: For the one that is currently at -2 it has been edited extensively from its original form. It was previously not very clear what the user was asking, which is probably where the downvotes came from (though not having cast either of them I can't say for sure)

Answer (score 9):

The question you cite as being at -2, used terminology from a game with *infamously, extremely precise definitions* in a way that made no sense. Because of that, and the way the question was structured, it would be quite incoherent to many people. It also didn't demonstrate an effort to understand the ability or rules involved - such questions are generally discouraged or disliked on Stack Exchange, and in some cases either *de facto* low quality or *de jure* off-topic.

It has been improved somewhat from its original form, but remains difficult to interpret.

The second question at +2 is neither of these things. It clearly asks about a specific component of a specific process of a specific format, and shows an understanding of both the basics involved as well as potential implications relevant to it.

It should perhaps have been split into two questions, related but not necessary to each other, but there are no problems with either actual question.

Comment: The main problem with the question was that even after a request to clarify the question, the question was not edited, until an other user made a big edit to clarify it